# SSL Certificate for Multi tenant application

Tags: ssl, dns, multi-tenant

We have an multi tenant application and working with apache tomcat webserver.
we are now pointing first tenant domain is  www.example.com= http://43.21.54.32:8080/tenant1.html and second tenant domain is www.example2.com=http://43.21.54.32:8080/tenant2.html. 
now we are planning to purchase SSL certificate to both domains. How could this possible..? Please help me on this.

Comment: Clients must use [Server Name Indication (SNI)](https://https.cio.gov/sni/). The client's `ClientHello` will include the server name `example.com` or `example2.com`. Apache will route it to the correct virtual server based on the name in the `ClientHello`. All modern clients use SNI.

Comment: thank you for the response.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what are you asking help for?

1. Is it for the purchasing certificates or
2. Setting up the scenario pointing first tenant domain is ***www.example.com***= http://43.21.54.32:8080/tenant1.html and second tenant domain is ***www.example2.com***=http://43.21.54.32:8080/tenant2.html.

If it is **1**, then you need to know that there is there is **SAN Certificates** (**Subject Alternative Name**), where you can have one certificate issued for multiple host names. The pricing for this is obviously on the higher side when compared to standard certificates. Here is a sample screenshot:
[image]

here is the link from **Digicert** for purchasing **SAN Certificate**: https://www.digicert.com/subject-alternative-name.htm

If it is **2**, then you need to setup reverse proxy. See this link for more details as it is similar to your scenario: https://tecadmin.net/setup-apache-as-reverse-proxy-for-tomcat/